# evento ajax update en el mismo form

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

Tengo problema para mostrar activar mostrar esta linea de codigo

```
<h:outputText id="activar" rendered="#{usuarioBean.activarPrograma}" value="Programa"/>
```

Cuando oprimo utilizo este evento de ajax

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{controladorRespuesta.usuarioActivarPrograma}" update="activar"/>
```

En el ambiente de prueba veo que si es llamado el proceso usuarioActivarPrograma, pero no veo que se actualice en la pagina.

Este es el código bean

```
    public void usuarioActivarPrograma(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {

    SelectOneRadio test = (SelectOneRadio) event.getSource();
    String value = (String) test.getValue();

    if(value.equals("director")) {
        usuarioBean.setActivarPrograma(true);
    }else {
        usuarioBean.setActivarPrograma(false);
    }
}
```

y esta es la pagina jsf

```
<p:tab title="Nuevo">
  <h:form id="form1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.cedula}" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><p:selectOneRadio value="#{usuarioBean.opcion}" >
             <f:selectItem itemValue="docente" itemLabel="Docente" />
             <f:selectItem itemValue="director" itemLabel="Director" />
                <p:ajax event="change" listener="# {controladorRespuesta.usuarioActivarPrograma}" update="activar"/>                             
          </p:selectOneRadio>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td><h:outputText id="activar" rendered="#{usuarioBean.activarPrograma}" value="Programa"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

la unica forma en que funciona es que haga este cambio

```
 <p:ajax event="change" listener="# {controladorRespuesta.usuarioActivarPrograma}" update="form1"/>
```

Pero me borra los campos del inputText

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan suministrar.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas actualizando todo el formulario, por lo que JSF vuelve a invocar tu Bean para eso. ¿Y si pruebas con: update="form1:activar"? Tienes que ser preciso sobre que parte del dom querés que se actualice. A veces es algo complicado sobretodo porque jsf autogenera ids para los elementos que no tienen uno

Comment: me aparece este error Cannot find component for expression "form1:activar"

Comment: A veces cuando es difícil saber como se generó el id, lo que te conviene hacer es mirar el dom generado con la consola de desarrollo de chrome o firefox. Inspeccioná el DOM y fijate con que id se generó el componente